# Using jQuery.jScroll with MVC 5

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-5, jquery-jscroll

I'm trying to implement infinite scrolling with the jScroll plugin y  Philip Klauzinski. I have included the jScroill js file along with jQuery and nothing is happening. Here's my view:

```
@model IEnumerable<AccessorizeForLess.ViewModels.DisplayProductsViewModel>

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Products";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/jQuery-jScroll.js"></script>
<link href="~/Content/Site.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $('.scroll').jscroll({
            autoTrigger: true
        });
    });
</script>
<h2>Products - Necklaces</h2>
<p>
    @Html.ActionLink("Create New", "Create")
</p>
<div id="container">
    <div class="scroll">
        @foreach (var item in Model)
        {

            <div class="itemcontainer">

                @Html.ActionLink(@item.Name, "Details", new { id = item.Id })
                <br />

                <div>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Price)</div>
                <div><img src="@item.Image.ImagePath" alt="@item.Image.AltText" title="@item.Image.AltText" /></div>
                <div>&nbsp;</div>
                <div>
                    Quantity: <input type="text" id="quantity" style="width:50px;" />&nbsp;
                    <button id="AddToCart" type="button" data-id="@item.Id" class="btn btn-default">Add to Cart</button>
                </div>
                <div style="height:35px;"></div>
                <hr />
            </div>

        }
    </div>
</div>
```

Has anyone ever used this plugin and know what I'm doing wrong?

**EDIT**

When I check the javascript console in Google Chrome is gives an error that jscroll is not a function

**EDIT**

Here is the Details code from the controller

```
public async Task<ActionResult> Details(int? id)
{
    if (id == null)
    {
        return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
    }
    Product product = await entities.Products.FindAsync(id);
    if (product == null)
    {
        return HttpNotFound();
    }

    DisplayProductDetailsViewModel model = new DisplayProductDetailsViewModel()
    {
        Id = product.ProductId,
        Name = product.ProductName,
        Description = product.ProductDescription,
        Price = string.Format("{0:C}",product.ProductPrice),
        Image = product.ProductImage
    };
    return View(model);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MVC 5 you need to use `@section scripts { }`. And you should load the jquery-1.10.2.min.js at the bottom of your layout. then render your scripts.

Layout:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
    <title> @ViewBag.Title</title>


    @if (ViewBag.MetaDescription != null)
    {
        <meta name="description" content="@ViewBag.MetaDescription" />
    }
    else
    {
        <meta name="description" content="" />
    }
    @if (ViewBag.MetaKeywords != null)
    {
        <meta name="keywords" content="@ViewBag.MetaKeywords" />
    }
    else
    {
        <meta name="keywords" content=""/>
    }
    @Styles.Render("~/Content/css")
    @Styles.Render("~/Content/themes/base/css")



</head>
<body>

            @Html.Partial("_LayoutHeader")

            @Html.Partial("_LayoutNav")






            @RenderBody()
            <hr />
            @Html.Partial("_LayoutFooter")




    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/bootstrap")

    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryui")




            @RenderSection("scripts", required: false)


</body>

</html>
```

Your View:

```
@model IEnumerable<accessorizeforless.viewmodels.displayproductsviewmodel>

@{
ViewBag.Title = "Products";
Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}



<h2>Products - Necklaces</h2>
<p>
    @Html.ActionLink("Create New", "Create")
</p>
<div id="container">
    <div class="scroll">
        @foreach (var item in Model)
        {

        <div class="itemcontainer">

            @Html.ActionLink(@item.Name, "Details", new { id = item.Id })
            <br />

            <div>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Price)</div>
            <div><img src="@item.Image.ImagePath" alt="@item.Image.AltText" title="@item.Image.AltText" /></div>
            <div>&nbsp;</div>
            <div>
                Quantity: <input type="text" id="quantity" style="width:50px;" />&nbsp;
                <button id="AddToCart" type="button" data-id="@item.Id" class="btn btn-default">Add to Cart</button>
            </div>
            <div style="height:35px;"></div>
            <hr />
        </div>

        }
    </div>
</div>

@section scripts {
<script src="~/Scripts/jQuery-jScroll.js"></script>
}

@section scripts {
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $('.scroll').jscroll({
            autoTrigger: true
        });
    });
</script>
}
```

the `@section scripts` will place the script at the very bottom of the page before the `</body>` tag and after the jquery loads. Jquery will load first before any scripts placed in a `@section scripts` on any view.

Hope this helps

Comment: It's still telling me that jscroll i not a function

Comment: Edited view to include jQuery-jScroll.js before your script

Comment: I do have one question, once it stop scrolling (reaches the end) when I click details it loads it right there in the Index page instead of taking me to the details page. It's only the last one that does it. Any ideas why?

Comment: @Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details", new { id=item.Id }

Comment: I added that and the last item still loads in the index view not the details view

Comment: Only the last record does this. all other records go to details page? I can not reproduce this with my records. What does the Details code from the controller look like.

Comment: Yes only the last record does this behavior. I edited my post to include the code from the Details method in the controller